# How to do a batch write, update and delete entities in low-level api datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, low-level-api

I want to add 100 entities (then update and delete them) to the datastore, but I don't know how to do that in a low level api. I did it in JDO. The documentation for low level is very scarce.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a collection of entities to put method - this will batch create/update the entities: [`datastoreService.put(Iterable<Entity>)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#put%28java.lang.Iterable%29) (collection of Entities).

You can also batch delete: [`datastoreService.delete(Iterable<Key> collection)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#delete%28java.lang.Iterable%29) (collection of Keys) or [`datastoreService.delete(Key.. keys)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#delete%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key...%29) (array of Keys)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is here: [Batch Operations](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Batch_operations).

I suggest you to take a look at the [async datastore api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/async) as well to improve even more the performance of your application.